# Fonts appear larger in chrome compared to IE

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have an MVC application whereby initially the fonts appeared larger when using the host name vs localhost.

I created an MVC app in vs 2013 with custom theme bootstrap styling.

I normally use chrome as my browser of choice during dev and testing - after some googling I found chrome when using localhost used 90% zoom vs domain name which is 100%. So really the problem was not being solved just hidden.

The requirement came up to use IE 10 but the fonts appeared much larger. I added a tag in the header of the layout that solved the issue for IE10 but adding chrome=1 has not solved the issue in chrome.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge chrome=1"/>
```

The only way to get the page to size correctly on a laptop is to reduce the view in chrome to 90% when using the domain.

IE works perfectly however chrome does not seem to be scaling correctly.

I looked at the network trace using localhost and domain name and all files load correctly.

I am really baffled. Any clues or directions to follow will be appreciated.

Comment: Check your display scaling: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display

Comment: I did check all of that and it appears to be correct. The issue might be in chrome actually I think. The font sizes scaled correctly in IE depending on the size of the display however the same does not happen in chrome. Somewhere along the net I read chrome made a fix with regards to fonts in it's latest release tired that but to no avail does it work.

Comment: So you set the display scaling to 100% (e.g. no scaling) and you still have the issue?

Comment: I set the display scaling (view/zoom) in IE and chrome both to 100%. IE "scales" correctly whereas Chrome does not.

Comment: As I said previously it seems like the FONTS are appearing much smaller in IE than in CHROME - which leads me to believe that CHROME might NOT be rendering the FONTS correctly, despite their new release. I might just be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Sure, I was referring to the scaling in Windows. Can you test it on another box and see if you can repro it?

Comment: Yes did that - I found out something interesting well for me that is. If you zoom out say to 90% on a web page in chrome, close the tab go back it will remember the zoom settings. So that's the work around for now. As to why it renders different in IE and Chrome is a mystery to me.